# instagram dev account: track hashtags

Tags: instagram, hashtag

Since there is no way to message the Instagram support directly, I'm trying my luck here. In case of asking a redundant question, please forgive us.

We're trying to use the Instagram API with a Nodejs web application, to track Instagram feeds for a specific hashtag. right now, there's a developer account in sandbox mode. Using a simple get request (https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/), we receive Instagram photos with a specific hashtag, which were posted by ourselves, but not from any public Instagram accounts. Since Instagram changes the access conditions for features like this, could you help us with my question?

Answer (score 0):

In sandbox mode you will only see your and your sandbox users' posts in API response, once you complete app, get approved by Instagram and go live, you will get all posts for hashtag search.

Comment: ok thank you. so i guess defining the scope to "basic" and "public content" will fit our needs ?

Comment: does instagram request the complete sourecode of the application?

Comment: so source code, they need to see how the ui flow and app looks like, you have to submit a video screencast

Comment: instagram denied the subscription, for following reasons:

"Your screencast does not show a test user logging into Instagram in your app. Please update your screencast to show the complete login experience.

Policy Violation (Incentivization): Your integration of write permissions shouldn't incentivize the use of Instagram actions...."

we decided to just use it, to crawl for hashtags and to display the pictures in our software. will this work out ?